# The target-entity User cannot be found in 'App\Entity\Slider#user'

Tags: symfony, symfony4

I try to get back an user (using getUser) from an other Entity (Slider); but this error is triggered:

`The target-entity User cannot be found in 'App\Entity\Slider#user'.`

This is my Slider entity:

```
namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Slider
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="slider", indexes={@ORM\Index(name="IDX_CFC71007A76ED395", columns={"user_id"})})
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Slider
{
    /**
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId(): int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * @param int $id
     */
    public function setId(int $id): void
    {
        $this->id = $id;
    }

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;


    /**
     * @return \User
     */
    public function getUser(): \User
    {
        return $this->user;
    }

    /**
     * @param \User $user
     */
    public function setUser(\User $user): void
    {
        $this->user = $user;
    }

    /**
     * @var \User
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="\User")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     * })
     */
    private $user;

}
```

I really don't understand what is wrong there, I also have read some other topic here, but none of them were able to unlock me.
I'm pretty sure the issue is quite simple, but I can't solve it.
Thanks for your help. Do not hesitate if you need more information.

Comment: Remove all backslashes before `User`, so instead of `\User` it should be just `User`

Comment: That was it thanks you very much.

Comment: No problem. Be so kind and accept my answer, and maybe upvote it ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove all backslashes before `User`, so instead of `\User` it should be just `User` :)